# How to create a dropdown list with predefined values but there should also be the option to add a new one to the list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list with predefined values but there should also be an option to add a new one to the list.

```
    <select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="">Enter new value</option>
    </select>
```

In the above code I want an option to add new `<option>` tag, with which I could add a new value to the list and post to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the solution with jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/pqkczuah/

or alternatively you can use the following:

```js
  $("#input").change(function() {
      if(this.value == "add") {
        varNewValue = prompt("Enter new value!");
        $("#input").append("<option value='"+varNewValue+"'>"+varNewValue+"</option>");
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="-">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="add">Add New</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the page respond, so chose the option vale

```
<option value="">New value</option>
```

have a script which onclick(); will make an text input box appear. When submitted send to a database and then make it a live dropdown.

Thats what I would do, long method but will get the job done and prevent further issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you could provide the user with a input of type text to set value/text for the option .

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#input');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var inp = document.querySelector('#newitem');
  
  //get input's value and create a option from it
  var val = inp.value;
  var option = new Option(val, val);
  
  select.add(option);
};
```

```html
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>

</select>

<input type="text" id="newitem">
<button>add option</button>
```